# google directory api - org name of root org unit path

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am trying to get the organization name of root organization. However in the below API, I cannot send orgUnitPath as empty.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/get

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Old topic, but I might just as well answer, as I was looking myself.
You can get the root OU, in at least one way, it's not pretty, but it works.

First you use [Orgunits: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list) to get a complete list of the units. The you loop through them until you find a unit with parentPath="/". Then you take the parentId of that unit and do a [Orgunits:  get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/get) using said "parentId" as "orgUnitPath".

Voila...
/Adam

Comment: To prevent needing to loop through to find a match, you can specify the root OU path `/` as the SearchBase and the List `Type` as `Children` to only return OrgUnit's directly underneath the root.

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround works only if there is at least one sub unit.

Answer (score 3):

The root org is always named '/' via the API no matter what it's called in the Control Panel.

Comment: I actually tried giving '/' in the 'Try it' section. It did not work. for the API to work, the orgUnit path should not start with '/'.  when I remove '/' from the root path, it becomes null. The api fails because org unit path is a required field and I am sending empty string.

Comment: What api call are you making?

Comment: Sorry, i see the orgunit/get link in your original post. You cannot get the root ou. You can only move users to it.