# Cannot get root Orgunit in Google Directory API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-directory-api

I am trying to get information about root organization unit. I tried to use *orgunits.list* and *orgunits.get* methods but both fails.

```
   const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth});
service.orgunits.list({
    customerId: 'my_customer',
    orgUnitPath: '/',
    type: 'all' 
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    const data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

*orgunits.list* returns just two values (if I don't have any sub units):

```
{kind: "admin#directory#orgUnits", etag: "..."}
```

and *orgunits.get* returns *not found* error:

```
   service.orgunits.get({
    customerId: 'my_customer',
    orgUnitPath: '/'
    // orgUnitPath: 'id:...'
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    const data = res.data;
    console.log(data);   
});
```

I succeeded to get the information about root org unit only when I added a sub unit then ran *orgunits.list* and then looked up a parent unit id in sub-unit as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776377/6651235).

So the question is how to get root orgunit or orgunit id if there is no subunits?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you want to do but getting the Root "/" organizational Unit on Google retrieves all the domain.